# app.config - how to remove file atribute from appSettings?

Tags: c#, xml

Programmatically, how do I remove the *File* Attribute from *appSettings* in App.Config? The line is:

```
<appSettings File="c:\thisApp\override.config">
```

I'd like it to become

```
<appSettings>
```

Comment: Not a duplicate: that thread covers he modification and saving of elements. My topic is about doing it with attributes.

Comment: Why you want to remove the *file* attribute? Run time will ignore the specified *file* if its not found!